# How send keystrokes using internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

What I need, is to trigger a keyboard shortcut on the client. If nothing appends then the user know that [my software](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/Outils/Xorg%E2%80%90fr/) will work and that he can download it *(as the page text explain)*.
However the shortcut is confusing because several keys have the same name. It would be nice to trigger the ᴡindows® shortcut by clicking on a link.

So I don’t want to simulate keypress event but really pull the keys remotely. ActiveX seems to be the solution, however it seems it is as trivial as using Flash Player.

I’ve read on an Stack Overflow anwser internet explorer have JavaScript extensions allowing some kind of OS control. But I can’t find that similar Stack Overflow post again.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. Sorry.

(If it were, that would pose a huge security risk. Consider what could happen if a web page could trigger Win+R and type in a command!)

Comment: Wrong, you can do it at least with activeX. *(which let you understand why it has been removed in edge)*. But activeX isn’t as easy as JavaScript.

Comment: @user2284570: No.  It is _completely impossible_ to do this without making the user accept a scary security warning.

Comment: Yes, it trigger a prompt from internet explorer warning that a content has been blocked, prompting to reload the page without restrictions. But I don’t care about those kinds of messages. The user have still a more difficult alternative to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is some sample code.

Use as you wish :)

```
Set Elements = IEDoc.getElementsByClassName("REQ")(0)
Elements.Value = 10001
Set objWSS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Elements.Focus
objWSS.SendKeys "^{TAB}"
DoEvents
objWSS.SendKeys ("{DOWN}")
DoEvents
objWSS.SendKeys ("{TAB}{RIGHT}")
DoEvents
```

Comment: You can't run that from a webpage.

Comment: @PieCrafted : Doesn’t seems to be usable in JavaScript file.